# What bounding box to use for a Miller projection?

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, tiles, extents, maptiler

I'm not a GIS expert at all and new to dealing with maps. My question is really basic. I'm basically asking for the extent of earth. Please help out anyway.

I'm trying to render tiles for a world map that I want to host. So I basically need three things: A map image file, specify a coordinate system, and a bounding box to declare the map's geographical location. Got the first two but struggling with the third.

My map is not a Mercator projection but a rectangular World Miller Cylindrical ESRI:54003 https://epsg.io/54003 (additionally, not sure if important, it's also unusual in that it centers on the Pacific ocean at 153°E).

Now my problem is that its spatial reference system is not in degrees but metres and I don't  know what bounding box I should specify. In a usual Mercator projection with a WGS 1984/ EPSG:4326 sorta coordinate system I'd define a bounding box of "-180 -90 180 90" degrees to cover the whole earth. What is the equivalent to that in metres?

In summary: What bounding box string should I use for a map of the whole earth in Miller projection?

Comment: How are you rendering these tiles?

Comment: I'm using MapTiler Desktop ( https://maptiler.com ). Seems to work well in theory. I just can't get decent output for my Miller projection because I lack the bounding box.